# VBA to control Access 2010 Line Chart Marker color

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, pivot-chart

I have created a pivot line chart in Access 2010.  I am trying to use VBA to format the lines and markers so that my charts all look the same regardless of the series name.  I can get everything to work except changing the marker color.  Here is what I am using....

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()

'Comp 1
Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).Line.Color = RGB(0, 128, 255)
Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).Line.Weight = 6
Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).marker.Size = 6
Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).marker.Style = 1
Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).MarkerForegroundColor = vbRed
```

I have tried many different iterations for the marker color but I keep getting "run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" no matter how I try it.  Any assistance is appreciated.

I updated code to

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim p As Long

'Comp 1
With Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0)
    .Line.Color = RGB(99, 66, 255)
    .Line.Weight = 6
    .marker.Size = 8
    .marker.Style = 2

pc = .Points.Count

For p = 1 To pc
    .Points(p).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = vbRed
Next
End With
```

but still have the same problem.  I added the `pc = .points.count` to verify accuracy.  Everything works except changing the marker color.

Comment: Not sure it's the same in Access, but try using the Point.MarkerForeGroundColor (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834722.aspx)

Comment: same issue as before

Comment: Update your code with the attempt you're using?

Comment: latest iteration `Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).Point.MarkerForegroundColor = vbRed`

Comment: You need to specify a point by index, e.g., `.Points(0).MarkerForegroundColor` etc. and may therefore need to do a loop over the `Points` collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Dim p as Long
With Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0)
    .Line.Color = RGB(0, 128, 255)
    .Line.Weight = 6
    .marker.Size = 6
    .marker.Style = 1
    For p = 1 to .Points.Count
        .Points(p).MarkerForegroundColor = vbRed
    Next
End With
```

The `MarkerForeGroundColor` is a property of a `Point` object, not a `Series` object. Documentation from Excel, but it should be the same across different Office Applications with VBA:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834722.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got it!! Thanks **David Zemens**
for pointing me in the right direction.  I just had to tweek the `.points` line and now it works perfectly.  One note, I also needed to adjust the `For` line since Access is 0 based.  Here is the final code.  Thanks all.

```
With Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0)
    .Line.Color = RGB(99, 66, 255)
    .Line.Weight = 6
    .marker.Size = 8
    .marker.Style = 2

pc = .Points.Count

For p = 0 To pc - 1
    .Points(p).Interior.Color = vbRed
Next
End With
```